# healpy: galactic and equatorial plane drawing fails

Tags: python, ipython, healpy

I am very new with healpy and python, but I would like to draw a skymap with the galactic plane and the equatorial plane in galactic coordinates. The first issue that I have is that I am not able to draw a strait line:

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

hp.mollview(title="Galactic coordinate map")
hp.graticule()

theta = [90., 90.]
phi = [-180., 180.]


hp.projplot(theta, phi, 'r-', coord='G')
pl.show()
```

I was trying to follow this documentation:
https://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/1.5.0/generated/healpy.visufunc.projplot.html

Also I am not sure where to get the coordinates for the galactic plane and the equatorial plane.

Comment: I started that code in ipython notebook, and it uses the coordinates 0-180 deg, so that is not the issue. Also I found this:   https://github.com/healpy/healpy/issues/109. Someone seems to have a similar issue with drawing lines in healpy

Comment: you are right, I remember I looked into this but I didn't find where the problem was...somebody needs to spend a couple of hours debugging this.

Comment: Does that mean there is no solution for that issue right now?

Comment: Yes, right, unfortunately we are not getting the help from other users we expected when we put the project on github, so it is up to us 2 core developers in our free time.

Comment: Oh wow! In that case thank you a lot for doing that at all! When I will be more advanced one day, I will give the help back that I get now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the bug in healpy is not fixed it's possible to generate enough points resulting into a line:

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

hp.mollview(title="Galactic coordinate map")
hp.graticule()

theta = [0.]*100
phi = np.arange(0, 360, 3.6)


hp.projplot(theta, phi, 'r-', coord='G')
pl.show()
```